# How to get Tizen App URL

Tags: tizen

I am developing apps for Tizen contest. And my apps are also published now when i am submitting app details on their website they are asking about app URL, I am unable to understand from where do i can get App URL.

I had tried mailing the support but they are not replying in any kind. And tomorrow is last date to submit app details to Tizen.

Regarding contest you can find more details on their website.

Please any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question "how to find url of app" I think Tizen store is not live yet, So it is might not be possible to provide app URL.

Though you can provide your app id or content id in the contest details form. As when i tried filling the contest form i had placed content id in the field where we have to provide app URL

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope this might be helpful.